# Counting difference in minutes using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate difference in time, for e.g 12:30pm-12:00am, not sure what I am doing wrong. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

```js
function CountingMinutesI(str) { 
 var times = str.split('-'); 
   var from = times[0];
   var to = times[1];
  
function timer(num){
 var hrs = num.split(':');  
  var min = hrs[1].slice(0,2);
  var ampm = hrs[1].slice(2);
   var totalMins = 0;
    
   var pmMins = if (ampm === 'pm'){
      return 720;
    }else
   return 0;
  
 var totalMins = hrs*60 + mins + pmMins ;
   return totalMins;
}
  var diff = timer(from) - timer(to);
   return diff;
}   


   
// keep this function call here 
CountingMinutesI("12:30pm-12:00am");
```

Comment: That's the not way to call. You need to use `CountingMinutesI("12:30pm-12:00am");`

Comment: just a silly question what is 12:30 pm in 24 hour notation?

Comment: @NinaScholz 12:30 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)

Comment: @Fearlessinc No you didn't. You haven't enclosed them inside any of the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var moment = require('moment');

function CountingMinutesI (str) {
   var timeStrings = str.split('-');
   var from = moment(timeStrings[0]);
   var to = moment(timeStrings[1]);
   var duration = moment.duration(to.diff(from));
   var minutes = duration.asMinutes();
   return minutes;
}

var diff = CountingMinutesI('12:30pm-12:00am');
```